# When a user removes my Chrome Extension, the storage associated with it gets removed also. Is there any way to request that this storage persists?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically, I use Chrome local storage to track usage of the extension. This allows me to put in place "Free User" limits, versus unlimited usage for "Paid Users."

However if a person simply removes, then re-installs the extension, it purges the data, and they're able to use the extension above and beyond the "Free User" level that they should be allowed to use it at.

Is there any way I can request in my extension code, that this chrome storage persists somehow, perhaps for a certain duration of time, after the extension gets removed? Can I request some kind of permission in the manifest for this?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is absolutely not, but the longer answer is that you absolutely can charge and ensure your extension isn't abused by implementing a serverless architecture. I just finished a browser extension that uses this methodology. There are several distinct components: (1) Auth0 is a great solution for managing auth / accounts, you can integrate it easily in a browser extension with ```chrome.identity```, (2) use AWS Lambda/DynamoDB to track the user, and (3) Stripe to manage subscriptions. (though you probably already have a payment solution in place, so use w/e that is!

Comment: Also, I recognize there is potentially an additional challenge in ensuring they don't create tons of free accounts and for that you technically have numerous options since auth0 gives IP information and/or you could require a CC for the free trial w/ your subscription provider

Comment: to add to @Jridyard - because it may not be clear - anything you're currently saving into storage is accessible to any user and they are free to delete, modify, and alter it all.

So even if you set up authentication just be sure you aren't storing any information you don't want the user to have. Just felt this was necessary as it appears to me like you may not understand that the user can access the storage your extension uses.

Comment: A lame workaround, assuming the users don't inspect your source code, may be to scatter the info in cookies of multiple random sites using some non-obvious way to identify it's your cookie. In onInstalled event you would get all cookies and find yours.